# ionic cordova build --device --release ios fails on Cordova 9

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3

While building for iOS, we are now receiving this message:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Volumes/Trabalho/AppName/platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName/Pods-AppName-dummy.m'
```

My Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 
   native-run  : 0.2.7 (update available: 0.2.8)

System:

   ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.1
   NodeJS     : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Does anyone has any idea of what is happening? Yesterday the code was building correctly, now it is giving this crazy error...

Answer (score 0):

Craziness... Problem was that "AppName" has spaces and accented characters. Since removing spaces and accented characters, build has resumed working.

I had no problem with this until the update of CocoaPods to 1.7.4.

Anybody facing the same situation?